# Php convert seconds to readable format with only required values

Tags: php

I have this function below.

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
}
```

Above function for example 172 seconds returns below

```
0 days, 0 hours, 2 minutes and 52 seconds
```

but i want it to be only

```
2 minutes and 52 seconds
```

or if its less than 60 seconds its should ignore minutes..

Comment: How can the return include days if there is no days in the function?

Comment: I am sorry see my updated function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$seconds=172;
function sec_to_time($seconds) {
$hours = floor($seconds / 3600);
$minutes = floor($seconds % 3600 / 60);
$seconds = $seconds % 60;
if($hours>0)
{
   return sprintf(" %d hours %02d , minutes %02d , seconds", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
else if($minutes>0)
{
  return sprintf("%02d minutes , %02d seconds", $minutes, $seconds);
}
else
{
  return sprintf("%02d seconds",  $seconds);
}
}
echo sec_to_time($seconds);
```

or new answer as per you update function

```
function secondsToTime($seconds) {
    $dtF = new DateTime("@0");
    $dtT = new DateTime("@$seconds");
    $a=$dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a');
    $h=$dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h');
    $i=$dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%i');
    $s=$dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%s');
    if($a>0)
    {
       return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%a days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
    }
    else if($h>0)
    {
        return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
    }
    else if($i>0)
    {
        return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format(' %i minutes and %s seconds');
    }
    else
    {
        return $dtF->diff($dtT)->format('%s seconds');
    }
}
echo secondsToTime(172);
```

Comment: this just returns 2:52 ? i need like 2 minutes , 52 seconds

Comment: @DevakiArulmami check answer now. update as per your new function

Comment: do not use the second method if u plan to add months and years tho